# AngularJS, Jasmine, and run()

Tags: angularjs, module, jasmine

It may be this question has already been answered, but I cannot find anything that addresses it so forgive me if I am reasking something that has obviously been answered somewhere else.

According to AngularJS documentation:

> **Run blocks** - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application. Only instances and constants can be
>   injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system
>   configuration during application run time.

I'm writing unit tests and need to test the following code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('htmlFwApp', []).run(['ApplicationModel',
  function(ApplicationModel) {
    ApplicationModel.mergeFromJSONAsync('application.config.json');
    // This code makes a GET call for 'application.config.json'
    // and merges it via _.extend with ApplicationModel.
  }
]);

beforeEach(module('htmlFwApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend) {
  $httpBackend.whenGET('application.config.json').respond({
    'applicationNameShort': 'Jasmine Config',
    'applicationNameLong': 'Jasmine Config',
    'applicationDescription': 'This is the test of everything!',
    'applicationKey': 'test'
  });
}));

describe('ApplicationModel Test', function() {
  it('Should properly inject and be defined',
    inject(function(ApplicationModel) {
      expect(ApplicationModel).toBeDefined();
    }));

  it('Should merge properties from the provided JSON',
    inject(function(ApplicationModel) {
      expect(ApplicationModel.applicationNameShort).toBe('Jasmine Config');
    }));
});
```

The problem is that the `run` method is not called before the test. Is there a way to trigger run to be called or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some digging and asking around, I found a solution. I set a $q promise on `ApplicationModel` and then in my test I wait for that promise to resolve:

```
  it('Should merge properties from the provided JSON',
    inject(function(ApplicationModel, $httpBackend) {
      runs(function () {console.log('starting!')});
      waitsFor(function () {
        return ApplicationModel.loadingPromise === undefined;
      });
      runs(function () {
        expect(ApplicationModel.applicationNameShort).toBe('Jasmine Config');
      });

      $httpBackend.flush();
    }));
```